# Combining variables to form one variable name?

Tags: python

Im making a D&D related program because i like doing character sheets by myself and im making it simpler but i've run into a problem

```
def calculateMod(x):
    for n in range (0):
        base= x -10
        base2=base/2
        nMod = math.floor(base2)
```

With the xMod variable i'm trying to take the Ability Score that they want to calculate the modifier for (if you don't understand exactly what i'm talking about its ok its not python related) however i've created the character into a class, so the strength for example is more of a variable less of a string, so if i want to calculate the modifier for strength i would put

```
calculateMod(character.strength)
```

so for xMod i would like it to be strengthMod so i can differentiate from my other modifiers.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is `range (0)` supposed to do? How many times do you expect that loop to execute?

Comment: There is no `xMod` variable. Do you mean `x` or `nMod`?

Comment: It would make sense for your class to have one dict for stats, and another for modifiers; so whenever your stats change, you can just iterate over the stat dict and update all the modifiers in the modifier dict. Because it's just two dictionaries, you don't need a separate variable for each stat; instead, it's just the dictionary items that scale that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to track all the characters mods, such as:

```
character.statmods = {
    "str": 3,
    "dex": 1,
    "con": 2,
    etc
}
```

if you really want them to each be a separate attribute on the character object, you can use setattr(object, attribute, value) to dynamically set attributes of an object, as long as the class of object is not restricted to using slots only.

```
stat = "strength"
setattr(character, stat+"Mod", nMod)

character.strengthMod #== nMod
```

Comment: A single dictionary with stat names as keys would be far superior.

Comment: yes that would probably be better. the question seemed focused more on the dynamic attribute naming.  I'll expand the answer.